# How pass output values between aws nested stacks in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

[Here](https://github.com/concon121/serverless-plugin-nested-stacks#readme) is readme about `serverless-plugin-nested-stacks` plugin. It makes possible to include nested stacks into main one. But how to pass values between stacks? For example I create a resouce in one nested stack - how to path it arn to another stack (nested or main one)?

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to export the resources from the corresponding nested stack like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  ...
Resources:
  ...
Outputs:
  o1:
    Description: ...
    Value: <your_resource_arn>
    Export:
      Name: <your_export_name>
```

To import the resource in other stack, you will need to use the intrinsic function `Fn::ImportValue`, like this:

```
Fn::ImportValue: <your_export_name>
```

For more information check the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)